# Eclipse get compile-time as a timestamp

Tags: java, eclipse, compile-time

Is it possible to get the build/compile time in Eclipse? (Java)

A bit like: "Build finished (took x.xxxx seconds)".

Comment: Thank you, it works. Question: When i then build with Maven, does it then build from scratch every time? (I'm trying to see which of two things are faster compiled).

Comment: Only if you do `maven clean ...`

Comment: Cool! Last question: Since i get different build-times, is it then possible to do x-number of builds and get the mean-build-time?

Comment: @Jeppe I haven't seen that anywhere, so I think you'd just run it X numbers of times and calculate the mean.